# How can I export a component containing and function and then use that function in another component?

Tags: reactjs

I am exporting a component with functions but when I try to use its functions in another component it is throwing an undefined. I have imported it properly but I can't seem to use the functions.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class TeamStore extends React.Component {
    _state: {
        team: "None",
        loaded: false
    }

    getState() {
        return this._state.team;
    }

    addTeam(team) {
        this._state.team = team;
        this.onChange();
    }

    onChange() {}
}
```

---

```
import React from 'react';
import Jumbotron  from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Jumbotron';
import TeamStores from './TeamStore';

export default class JumbotronNews extends React.Component {
    getStateFromStore() {
        return  TeamStores.getState(); //this is the one throwing the error

    }

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = this.getStateFromStore();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        TeamStore.onChange = this.onChange;
    }

    onChange() {
        this.setState(this.getStateFromStore());
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <Jumbotron>
                    <h1 style={{"marginLeft": "270px"}}>{this.state.team}</h1>

                  </Jumbotron>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: `TeamStore` looks more like a collection of utility methods and not a react class. You might also want to look into Flux or Backbone for handling data and events in React.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems.

- You defined `TeamStore` as a class, but you're using it like a regular object that has functions defined on it. If you want to keep it as a class, you'll have to instantiate it first before calling the functions.
- You defined the `TeamStore` class as an extension of `React.Component`, but you're not using it as a React component.
- In your `JumbotronNews` file, you import `TeamStore` as `TeamStores`, but you use it `componentDidMount` as `TeamStore`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a **Mixin** , here is an example:

```
var SetIntervalMixin = {
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.intervals = [];
  },
  setInterval: function() {
    this.intervals.push(setInterval.apply(null, arguments));
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.intervals.map(clearInterval);
  }
};

var TickTock = React.createClass({
  mixins: [SetIntervalMixin], // Use the mixin
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {seconds: 0};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.setInterval(this.tick, 1000); // Call a method on the mixin
  },
  tick: function() {
    this.setState({seconds: this.state.seconds + 1});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <p>
        React has been running for {this.state.seconds} seconds.
      </p>
    );
  }
});
```

Check Mixin on this page : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Also a different implementation based on ES6 is possible : https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750

Comment: I'm trying to implement this guy's "sideways communication". Is he using mixins as well? 
https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/04-less-simple-communication.md

Comment: No it's not a mixin, not sure this is adapted for your case. check the react link I posted and look for "mixin"

Comment: Should I continue along this route for my use case and look into mixins. or is this link more appropriate: 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-simple-shopping-cart-with-react-js-and-flux

Comment: You seems lost flux is another thing that you may use but this is not directly related to your problem, all you need is a file containing functions that are used inside several components, mixin is the simplest way to do that, if you want to use the ES6 version check the second link, otherwise just use mixin.